# How to make a tree using as few faces as possible?

Tags: particles, vertices, faces, hair

I have to make a tree and use it in a game, but when I use sapling tree add-on I get too many faces and I need them to be as few as possibe. Can you tell me what is the best way to make this kind of tree? I want it to look more realistic, I don't wat to make low polly tree. Also I tried using hair technique, but it didn't work for me: [image]

Comment: are you supposed to make close-up to the trees? Otherwise you could simply cross several planes with pictures of a tree taken from different angles, with alpha layers to make each plane transparent?

Comment: yeah he means that

Comment: well he should give some precisions because it would change a lot of things, if he needs some close-ups on the branches he can do it with Image Textures and Hair particles, if the tree is several meters away, no need for Image Textures, etc... A tuto made by CG Geek on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQUO9yL2vYQ&feature=youtu.be&t=2382